# Resize large images with mogrify (ImageMagick) but leave small images unaffected

Tags: resize, image-processing, imagemagick, mogrify

Images can be resized using mogrify from the ImageMagick suite:

```
mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

But this will resize images so that the largest dimension is 256px, including images that are smaller than 256px to begin with (like 100x100px avatars).

How can I exclude the smaller images from being affected?
i.e. I want the largest dimension to be *no more than* 256px

(Preferably I will be able to do this with ImageMagick suite, or at least without installing anything additional).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
mogrify -resize '1280x1024>' *.jpg
```

Do make sure to back up though.

Comment: While it works, it still opens and re-saves the images it doesn't resize (it can make a Windows Paint PNG smaller without affecting the image's pixels). While harmless quality-wise, it eats CPU and disk bandwidth needlessly...

Answer (score 1):

`mogrify -resize '256x256>' *.jpg` also modifies images it doesn't resize and changes their image data. This doesn't:

`identify -format '%w %h %i\n' *.jpg|awk '$1>256||$2>256{print$3}'|xargs mogrify -quality 93 -resize 256x256`

Or if the paths of the files contain spaces, single quotes, double quotes, or tabs:

`identify -format '%w %h %i\n' *.jpg|awk '$1>256||$2>256'|cut -d\  -f3-|xargs -d\\n mogrify -quality 93 -resize 256x256`